# Extract year YYYY from date DD.MM.YYYY as new variable in R

Tags: r, as.date

I have a field (variable) `data2$DatumZalozenia` with dates as follows `06.12.2013`. Format of the values in the variable is `DD.MM.YYYY`. The variable is type `chr`.
I need to extract the year out of the date and create new variable `data2$RokZalozenia` in a format `YYYY`. I need to do that in R. Can somebody please help me on this?

```
data2$RokZalozenia <- as.Date((data2$DatumZalozenia), format = "%d.%m,%Y")
```

Comment: The comma in the format should be a period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R base `sub`

```
> df$newDate <-sub(".*(\\d{4})$", "\\1", df$date1)
> df
       date1 newDate
1 06.12.2013    2013
2 06.12.2014    2014
3 06.12.2015    2015
```

data from @jpsmith

Comment: I would favor this solution, especially since OP has the dates as character and only needs the year. It makes no sense to first convert it to a date first and then extract the year from that.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg I agree - this is much more elegant and pragmatic than my solution, though the tools used in the date-conversion could work for other/future readers who have different data formats, so will leave mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lubridate` package functions `year` and `mdy`:

```
x <- "06.12.2013"
lubridate::year(lubridate::mdy(x))
# [1] 2013
```

Or in base R:

```
format(as.Date(x, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), "%Y")
# [1] "2013"
```

For the application in a data frame to create a new variable:

```
df <- data.frame(date1 = c("06.12.2013", "06.12.2014", "06.12.2015"))
# Lubridate approach
df$newDateLubridate <- lubridate::year(lubridate::mdy(df$date1))
# Base R approach
df$newDateBaseR <- format(as.Date(df$date1, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), "%Y")

#        date1 newDateLubridate newDateBaseR
# 1 06.12.2013             2013         2013
# 2 06.12.2014             2014         2014
# 3 06.12.2015             2015         2015
```